# Show values on POST

Tags: javascript, php, html

Working on a really simple form for a district site. I have a really simple form in PHP.

```
 <form method="post">
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Enter Age and Weight</legend>
   <label>Age:</label>
   <input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo @$_POST['age'] ?>">
   <label>weight:</label>
   <input type="text" name="weight">
   <div>
    <button class="btn" type="submit" name="action" value="enter">Enter</button>
   </div>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
```

What I am trying to do is when the user presses the enter button, I want to alert the user of what they have entered.

This is what I have so far in my HTML.

```
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
<form action="/index.php" onsubmit="" method="POST">
<script>
alert(document.getElementsByName("age").value);
</script>
</form>
</body>
```

However, I keep seeing "undefined". I am assuming that is happening because on page load my script is being run instead of when the user presses the submit button. Kind of confused how to just do a simple alert. Appreciate any help.

Comment: This sounds like an annoying behavior to me. Surely the users knows what they've entered. They can read it in the textbox.

Comment: Nevertheless, maybe you're looking for the javascript confirm() function?

Comment: It's not a duplicate because in his case he's not calling the function that sends the alert correctly, because he's calling it when page loads (without events). In the question he says that he wants to show the alert only when the form is submitted (enter button pressed).

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("age").value`  ElementS plural is not one element but a collection/list, so how does it have a `.value`? It doesn't.  Add an `id='age'` and use `document.getElementById("age").value`

Comment: Eventually I'll remove it, I just want show it now for me. Really more for myself to see what's going on when the user presses the submit button. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You must insert your code in a **function** that you must attach to a **event** handler like `onsubmit`, something like this:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="showData();">
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function showData() {
    alert(document.getElementsByName("age")[0].value);
}
```

I've inserted `[0]` in your Javascript code because document.getElementsByName returns you an Array of elements, in your case, this Array, obviously contains only one value that is retrievable on the index 0 (first index of any array).

Comment: Thank you @Syncro! I tried that but I am not getting any values to appear. I am just going straight through to my dummy landing page. Would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: This is what I have at the moment:

<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
<form action="/index.php" onsubmit="showdata()" method="POST">

</form>

<script type=text/javascript>
function showdata() {
    alert("HI");    
}
</script>
</body>

Answer (score -2):

```
<form method="post" id="myform">
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Enter Age and Weight</legend>
   <label>Age:</label>
   <input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo @$_POST['age'] ?>" id="age">
   <label>weight:</label>
   <input type="text" name="weight">
   <div>
    <button class="btn" type="button" name="action" value="enter" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('age').value);document.getElementById('myform').submit()">Enter</button>
   </div>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: I'm still seeing undefined. :/